# How to link two projects django

Tags: python, django

I need to link two projects Django. both of them project are run in the same server. What tools or file I need for this goal? when I click on some button in my current project's page I should get a page from the other project.. Can you suggest a way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create REST APIs in one project and invoke the API data from the other. The same way you link a python flask project with ReactJS

Answer (score 1):

You could use subdomains and redirect the user to the right subdomain.

```
Webserver:
|
|-Subdomain 1
|    |
|    |-first Django Project
|
|-Subdomain 2
|    |
|    |-second Django Project
```

Hope I could help you.

I would recommand you to use nginx (https://nginx.org/en/) that redirects you to the django project.